# Advanced Custom Fields - Repeater - Gallery

Tags: php, wordpress, repeater, flexslider, advanced-custom-fields

Ok, im having major trouble getting my head around this custom fields problem.

I can use custom post types but this is another level that I just cant seem to understand.

Basic overview: I have a single.php file with a thumbnail slider (flex slider) which also has some information next to each slide. See the below link to screenshot to give you a better idea.

http://pagedev.co.uk/richmond/show.png

I have set up my custom fields and I am using the repeater field to populate each slider thumbnail, large image and information on the left.

I cant seem to get my head around how this is going to work.

Below is my html:

```
<div class="center-container">
            <div class="section group">
                <div class="col span_12_of_12">
                    <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">

                      <ul class="slides">
                            <li>
                                <img src="thumbnail image" />
                            </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="section group">
                <div class="col span_3_of_12">
                    <div class="painting-description">
                        <p><strong>Paiting Title</strong></p>
                        <p>type of painting</p>
                        <p>size of painting</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col span_9_of_12">
                    <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
                      <ul class="slides">
                            <li>
                                <img src="main painting" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

As you can see I have a thumbnail image li item set up, a main painting li item set up and the painting title, type and size within a separate div.

My Overall repeater field is called: show_paintings

My custom fields are

Painting Title : painting_title

Type: type

Size of Painting: size

Thumbnail of painting: thumbnail

Main Painting Image: main_painting

I have tried using the methods on http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/repeater/ but am struggling to understand which one I need to use.

My posts just seem to flow down the page rather than into the slider. And also the description on the left needs to change for each large image that appears as each image has its own information.

I am new to wordpress and php so any help would be very helpful!

Thank you in advance

Lee

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to have the thumbnails as a carousel? If so you only have one thumbnail within your HTML, also I don't believe wordpress or PHP would come into a carousel. Are you trying to change the main image upon clicking on it's associated thumbnail - if so you'll need to put an event on the thumbnail click and put some attributes on each thumbnail to pick up and replace the main one.

Comment: Yeah I removed my other list items to just simplify it The carousel scrolls accross and the slider fades below as the thumbnails are clicked. You can see an example here: http://pagedev.co.uk/richmond/show-open.html The plugin all works fine as youll see its just bringing in the content from wordpress

Comment: Then what do you want to do with it? What's the issue?

Comment: I need to populate it with content from wordpress rather than being static html. I have tried using this http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/repeater/ but its not working.